# Changing database for a DBI::dbConnect connection

Tags: r, database, dplyr, odbc

When using dplyr over DBI interactively, I would connect as follows:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 driver='some_sql_server_driver',
                 server='some_server',
                 database='some_db_1',
                 trusted_connection='yes'
                 )
some_var <- tbl(con, 'some_table')
```

Now if I want to explore another database (say 'some_db_2') in the same server, is it possible to switch without closing existing connection (ie. database='some_db_2')?

Comment: It depends on the DBMS. If you are using MS SQL Server, then `DBI::dbExecute(con, 'use "some_db_2"')` should work.

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of that, BUT...  while this is interesting and possible, on reflection I think it's bad practice. The original connection is still shown as active in RStudio 'Connections' pane, without indication of change, leading to confusion. Better to close/reopen or create separate connection. Thanks!